# Bash how to remove centos packages without manual intervention, uninstall SSM agent in amazon linux 2

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, yum

I am spinning up and `EC2` instance and I am s setting up `data users` where I am trying to remove `ssm` agent as below:

```
sudo yum erase amazon-ssm-agent –y
```

But the problem in the above code is, even though I have passed `-y` it doesn't get it apparently, because I am getting the below prompt (I logged in to the instance and tried the same commands I have put in the data user section):

[image]

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

This is so strange, the character I have given for the `-y` is not the hypen. I could fixed that after retyping the `-y`

Answer (score 0):

`-y` is an option and options go before the command. So it should be:

```
sudo yum -y erase amazon-ssm-agent
```